# Log in to wordpress after executing another form function

Tags: login, plugin-mailchimp, remote-login

This is a unique situation.  Basically, the site I'm building has a login form on the home page that also has fields that will be used for signing up for a mailing list, but only if a checkbox is checked.   I want to set it up so that the action url I'm posting the form to will, after running the subscription code for the mailing list, then submit the pertinent fields on the form to log the user in to Wordpress.

This is what I have thus far on the action.php file I'm submitting the form to:

```
<?
$url = '/wp-login.php';
$data = array('log' => $_POST['log'], 'pwd' => $_POST['pwd'],'redirect_to'=> $_POST['redirect_to']);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


if ($_POST['subscribe'] == 'yes') {

$api_key = "KEYKEY";
$list_id = LISTLIST";
require('Mailchimp.php');

$email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
$merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>htmlentities($_POST['fname']), 'LNAME'=>htmlentities($_POST['lname']) );

$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($Mailchimp);

try{
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => htmlentities($_POST['stripeEmail']) ), $merge_vars );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof \Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed) {
    // In case they are already subscribed:
    $errors[] = '';
} else {
    // In case something else went wrong.
    $errors[] = '';
}
};
```

}; 
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hook [`wp_authenticate`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate) on a normal form submit, you can make a quick detour to your subscribe function before you continue to authenticate.

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_by_email' );

function wp_authenticate_by_email( $username ) {

    // check for subscribe action
    $is_subscribe = 'yes' == $_POST[ 'subscribe' ];

    // invalid username 
    if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) {

        // lookup as email
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
        if ( $user ) {

            $email    = $username;
            $username = $user->user_login;

            if ( $is_subscribe ) {

                // subscribe to mailing list
                do_subscribe( $email );
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    // lookup user by login
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    if ( $user ) {

        // get email from user login
        $email = $user->user_email;
        if ( $is_subscribe ) {

            // subscribe to mailing list
            do_subscribe( $email );
        }
    }
}

function do_subscribe( $email ) {

    if ( empty( $email ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // maybe check for password ????

    // do subscribe actions

    sleep( 2 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Gonna try it out.  stupid question: Since this is a wp function, where will this php file go?  Does it have to be in the theme file, or can it go to the action.php file?

Comment: It's best to put in your theme folder or plugin folder. If it's specific to a theme...  then keep with the theme. As for file, themes start with functions.php and you can just include it there as a separate file or keep all your code in one file - whichever is best for you.